# Cordova Plugin - stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString returning empty value

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins

i seems to be not able to receive any return value from `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` function call at my cordova plugin

Basically I am trying to get the active element in my page, and change my keyboard type based on the 'active element'

I registered `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` during the plugin initialise, and fire the javascript when the keyboard will be showing listener.

Here is my code at plugin initialise

```
-(void)pluginInitialize{
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

Here is my code when keyboard will show, inside my plugin

```
- (void)onKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
    NSString *script = @"document.activeElement";

    if ([self.webView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        NSString * result = [(UIWebView*)self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }
}
```

The result seems to always return empty string. Is there anything that i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manage to solve it by changing to `document.activeElement.type` instead.

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` seems to not able to return object or javascript object.